# Ambient occlusion bake stops at 0 percent

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake textures from high-poly mesh to low-poly. Normals and vertex colors baking right, but ambient occlusion baking resets at 0%. I can see it start baking, but stop after bake of small part, in several seconds after start.  What can be the reason? Here is screenshot of my project:
[image]

And a gif, to make it clear: 
[image]

Comment: Ambient occlusion for me usually take a long time to bake. It can be 0% for a while. Just wait

Comment: Its not freezing. It just resets, turning off. Like you can see at the picture.

Comment: To me baking just finishes its work and turns off. You can see tiny bits of white appearing in the UV islands corners, once it appears around all UV islands baking stops. Probably change AO settings for the scene. Also is there any particular reason to have Bias at 0.001 and Distance at 0? It would be more logical to have the other way around. Note also material in Node editor is for Cycles while active render engine is Internal